# what is the difference between unicorn and unicorn_rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, unicorn

So...what is the difference between `unicorn` and `unicorn_rails`
When should I use one or another?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

It is officially answered in https://blog.engineyard.com/2010/everything-you-need-to-know-about-unicorn:

**What is the unicorn executable?  What is the unicorn_rails executable?**

The `unicorn` executable is a Rack-only tool modeled after Rack’s “rackup” and is recommended for Rack applications. `unicorn_rails` was made to be an easier transition for users of pre-Rack versions of Rails. The manpage encourages Rails 3 users to use plain `unicorn` instead.

**What’s the difference?**

From the `unicorn_rails` manpage, some conventions of `unicorn_rails` are modeled after `script/server` found in Rails. It creates directories under “tmp” like `script/server` and the `-E/–environment` switch sets `RAILS_ENV` instead of `RACK_ENV`.

Apart from that, in my experience, some gems may need unicorn_rails in particular, like activeadmin (see [this](https://github.com/gregbell/active_admin/issues/298#issuecomment-1589377))

Also, [manpage:](http://unicorn.bogomips.org/unicorn_rails_1.html)

> It is designed to help Rails 1.x and 2.y users transition to Rack, but
>   it is NOT needed for Rails 3 applications. Rails 3 users are
>   encouraged to use unicorn(1) instead of unicorn_rails(1). Users of
>   Rails 1.x/2.y may also use unicorn(1) instead of unicorn_rails(1).