# How to start rails server in production mode using unicorn and config file?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unicorn

I add `Gem 'unicorn'` to Gemfile and call `rails server unicorn -e production`, but I get a load error. Then I add `Gem 'unicorn_rails'`, then call `rails server unicorn -e production`, but I can't find the socket file. So I am considering if it doesn't use the `config/unicorn.rb` file as the configuration? So I call `unicorn_rails -c config/unicorn.rb -E production -D`, but I get another error `text file busy`.

So now I am stuck in this matter, could you help me? :)

Comment: According to this http://stackoverflow.com/a/12326124/474597, just use 'unicorn' gem not the 'unicorn_rails' gem.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

It should be something looks like:

```
bundle exec unicorn -E production -c config/unicorn.rb
```

and you should only need `unicorn` gem

Comment: I think you have answered my question(about using unicorn and configuration), thank you. BTW, this command raises another error:`
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0-turbo/gems/unicorn-4.2.1/lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:202:in `rename': Text file busy - (/vagrant/ruby-china/tmp/pids/0.2628933382622929.13474, /vagrant/ruby-china/tmp/pids/unicorn.pid) (Errno::ETXTBSY)`, could you help me?

Answer (score 5):

`bundle exec unicorn -p $PORT -c ./config/unicorn.rb`

works for me

I put it in the Procfile and then use [Foreman](https://github.com/ddollar/foreman) to start it off by entering

`foreman start`

Comment: where do you define the value for the $PORT variable?

Comment: same question... i can run bundle exec unicorn -p 5000 -c ./config/unicorn.rb fine, but not bundle exec unicorn -p $PORT -c ./config/unicorn.rb

Comment: Add -D option to daemonize it

Answer (score 0):

```
web: bundle exec unicorn -p $PORT -c ./config/unicorn.rb

service unicorn_projectName start
```

works for me