# RAILS_ROOT Not Correct When Launching Unicorn with Capistrano deploy on rbenv

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, capistrano, unicorn, rbenv

MyApp is set up using:
ubuntu
rbenv
ruby 2.0
rails 4.0
unicorn
capistrano

With Capistrano's deploy strategy, the path to my app is /srv/www/my_app/current/
I'd expect to have RAILS_ROOT be the same.

When I am logged onto my remote server, am in that path, and run:

```
unicorn_rails -c /srv/www/my_app/current/config/unicorn.rb -D
```

I get the following error in the unicorn.stderror.log:

```
/home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/bin/unicorn_rails must be run inside RAILS_ROOT: #<LoadError: cannot load such file -- /srv/www/my_app/config/boot>
```

I've tried all sorts of things to set RAILS_ROOT, with no luck.

1. I thought RAILS_ROOT was actually Rails.root now
2. I saw somebody post that it should be defined in boot.rb but that would mean that the load error above is finding boot.rb and then complaining that it can't find it.

Comment: Why are you using `unicorn_rails`? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12325923/what-is-the-difference-between-unicorn-and-unicorn-rails it seems that is *not* recommended.

Comment: Well the last time I started a rails app, passenger was the big thing.  This is my first go at unicorn and this was what multiple tutorials showed. In other words, probably no good reason.  I'll check the linked thread.

Comment: Oi bozhe moi, that did it. If you want to put that as the answer to the question, I'll mark it as answered (I'll close it as answered tomorrow, otherwise)

Comment: Nah, it's okay - my answer was pretty much a link-only thing which is frowned upon here as a formal answer. Glad it fixed your issue though!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From Deefour's comment, I switched from using unicorn_rails to unicorn executable.